# Arrange an array based on another array filled with “<” and “>” symbols

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays. One array of size `n` is filled with `<` and `>` symbols. The second array is of size `n+1` and having integer numbers. I have to arrange the second array in such a manner so that it can satisfy the conditions from the first array.Please note that first array can not be modified.

```
conditionArray = ['>', '<', '<', '<', '>'];

numArray = [12, 9, 1, 11, 13, 2];
```

Possible output:

```
[9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 2]
```

Comment: What is the relation between the two arrays, exactly? What does `>` mean?

Comment: @Dai It’s “greater than” and “less than”. It can be read as `9 > 1 < 11 < 12 < 13 > 2`.

Comment: @Xufox there can be multiple arrangements of `numArray` that satisfy `conditionArray`. What determines the output permutation?

Comment: @Dai Well, he wrote this was a “_possible_ output”.

Comment: And that complicate things a little - do we need all possible outputs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like some kind of assignment and you need to show minimal effort to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @Amit Come on guys, the question is interesting. Do you really need to close it?

Comment: why to close, just one possible output would be ok. No need to find all possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

1) Use a built-in sorting method on the data.  This satisfies `conditionArray = ['<', '<', '<' ...]`.

2) Loop through your `conditionArray` and for each `>` take the final element (the largest one) and insert it into the current index shifting every other element.  Otherwise, the `<` is already satisfied and can be skipped.

In your example, the array will go through these intermediate states:

```
12, 9, 1, 11, 13, 2 //start

1, 2, 9, 11, 12, 13 // initial sort

13, 1, 2, 8, 11, 12 // index 0 of condition is a > so insert the last element at index 0
13, 1, 2, 8, 11, 12 // < is NOP
13, 1, 2, 8, 11, 12 // < is NOP
13, 1, 2, 8, 11, 12 // < is NOP 
13, 1, 2, 8, 12, 11 // index 4 of condition is a > so insert the last element at index 4
```

A very basic implementation:

```js
conditionArray = ['>', '<', '<', '<', '>'];
numArray = [12, 9, 1, 11, 13, 2];

numArray.sort( function(a, b) {return a -b ; /*lazy number comparison*/ });
console.log(numArray);
var size = numArray.length;
conditionArray.forEach( function(comparison, index) {
    //ignore '<'
    if (comparison == '>')
    {
        var finalElement = numArray[size - 1];
        numArray.splice(index, 0, finalElement); //insert the element
    }
    console.log(numArray);
        
});

numArray = numArray.slice(0, size); //remove all the extra stuff at the end

console.log(numArray);
```

This code is heavy in its usage of insertions.  It will work fine with link lists since insertion is a constant time operation, but it won't scale too well with arrays. If your insertions are computationally expensive (like is typical of arrays), you can instead just insert elements one at a time in an auxiliary array.

```js
conditionArray = ['>', '<', '<', '<', '>'];
numArray = [12, 9, 1, 11, 13, 2];

numArray.sort( function(a, b) {return a - b; /*lazy number comparison*/ });
console.log(numArray);
var size = numArray.length;
var newArray = [];
var numInsertedFromBack = 0;

conditionArray.forEach( function(comparison, index) {
    if (comparison == '>')
    {
        var biggestElementNotAlreadyInserted = numArray[size - 1 - numInsertedFromBack];
        newArray.push(biggestElementNotAlreadyInserted);
        numInsertedFromBack += 1;
    }
    else {
        //just insert the next element
        //since we inserted stuff out of turn, we need 
        //to account for each skip, and backtrack that many times
        var smallestElementNotAlreadyInserted = numArray[index - numInsertedFromBack];
        newArray.push(smallestElementNotAlreadyInserted);
    }
    console.log(newArray);
});

//need to manually add the straggling final element
//since the comparisons are of array.length - 1
newArray.push(numArray[size - 1 - numInsertedFromBack]);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: If you copy the data into a second array then, at the cost of extra memory, you could avoid the cost of array insertions.

Comment: @Penguino that's a great idea.  I've updated to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
conditionArray = ['>', '<', '<', '<', '>'];
numArray = [12, 9, 1, 11, 13, 2];
isComplete = false;
console.log(numArray);
 while (isComplete == false) {
  isComplete = true;
  for (i = 0; i < conditionArray.length; i++) {
   if ((conditionArray[i] == ">" && numArray[i] < numArray[i+1]) || (conditionArray[i] == "<" && numArray[i] > numArray[i+1])){
        isComplete = false;
        temp = numArray[i];
        numArray[i] = numArray[i+1];
        numArray[i+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
 document.write(numArray);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```